# Rounding Down to nearest whole number - am I cheating or is this more than adequate?

Tags: java

Essentially, if the number generated is 2.3 then if I subtract .5 it will then be 1.8 but the rounding function will make it 2, which is what I want. Or if the answer is 2.99999 and I subtract .5, the answer is 2.49999 which should round down to 2 which is what I want. My question is if the answer is 2 even and I subtract .5, the answer is now 1.5, so will it still round up to 2.

```
temp1_1= Math.round(temp2_2/(360/temp_value)-.5);
```

this is my line of code for this.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Even simpler and potential faster

```
double d = 2.99999999;
long l = (long) d; // truncate to a whole number.
```

This will round towards 0.  Math.floor() rounds towards negative infinity. Math.round(x - 0.5) also rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: I believe this will round negative numbers *up*.

Comment: from what i know i don't think i will ever have a negative value. the way i have it working so far. was a quick fix i needed. if any issues arise in the future i will make a change. thanx all for the info

Answer (score 43):

There is already a function to do that. It's called [floor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

```
double d = Math.floor(2.9999) //result: 2.0
```

Answer (score 15):

Everyone always wants to use fancy functions, but forgets about the humble modulus. My solution:

```
number = x-(x%1);
```

subtracts the remainder of division by one, so x = 2.999 will = 2, 3.111 will = 3 and so on. The cool thing about this is that you can round down the multiple of anything just by changing that 1 into whatever you like.

Comment: In my case, I needed to round down to nearest thousand, so your solution turned out to be a more elegant solution: `rounded = value - value % 1000`.  Nice.

Comment: Oh I like this - I was looking for the opposite of prior commenter (hundreths), and this works for me:  `rounded = value - (value % .01)`